# How to get the date a status changes in a time series?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following problem: I have a timeline of a machine's lifecycle events:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #machineStatus

CREATE TABLE #machineStatus
(
    machineID VARCHAR(255),
    machineStatus VARCHAR(255),
    statusDate DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO #machineStatus (machineId, statusDate, machineStatus)
VALUES
('01255999', '2019-11-01',  '1 - InStorage'),
('01255999', '2019-12-01',  '1 - InStorage'),
('01255999', '2020-01-01',  '1 - InStorage'),
('01255999', '2020-02-01',  '1 - InStorage'),
('01255999', '2020-03-01',  '1 - InStorage'),
('01255999', '2020-04-01',  '1 - InStorage'),
('01255999', '2020-05-01',  '1 - InStorage'),
('01255999', '2020-06-01',  '1 - InStorage'),
('01255999', '2020-07-01',  '1 - InStorage'),
('01255999', '2020-08-01',  '1 - InStorage'),
('01255999', '2020-09-01',  '1 - InStorage'),
('01255999', '2020-11-01',  '1 - InStorage'),
('01255999', '2020-12-01',  '1 - InStorage'),
('01255999', '2020-12-15',  '1 - InStorage'),
('01255999', '2021-01-01',  '2 - RentedOut'),
('01255999', '2021-03-01',  '1 - InStorage'),
('01255999', '2021-04-01',  '1 - InStorage'),
('01255999', '2021-04-02',  '2 - RentedOut'),
('01255999', '2021-04-05',  '3 - Service'),
('01255999', '2021-04-15',  '4 - Repairs'),
('01255999', '2021-04-20',  '2 - RentedOut'),
('01255999', '2021-05-27',  '5 - Sold')
```

I need to create a new column where I have to present the last date a status has changed:

```
SELECT
    s.*,
    (SELECT MAX(ss.statusDate) 
     FROM #machineStatus ss 
     WHERE ss.machineId = s.machineId 
       AND ss.machineStatus <> s.machineStatus 
       AND ss.statusDate < s.statusDate) AS statusChangeDate
FROM #machineStatus s
ORDER BY s.statusDate
```

[Run with SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/42f6f/1)

[Output](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/71e215/1/0)

I seem not get it to some extend, but my problem is that I can't figure out how to get the date for the first/earliest status of the machine. All NULL values in the statusChangeDate column should be 2019-11-01, like so:

```
|machineID  | machineStatus |           statusDate |     statusChangeDate |
|-----------|-------------- |----------------------|----------------------|
|  01255999 | 1 - InStorage | 2019-11-01T00:00:00Z | 2019-11-01T00:00:00Z |
|  01255999 | 1 - InStorage | 2019-12-01T00:00:00Z | 2019-11-01T00:00:00Z |
|  01255999 | 1 - InStorage | 2020-01-01T00:00:00Z | 2019-11-01T00:00:00Z |
|  01255999 | 1 - InStorage | 2020-02-01T00:00:00Z | 2019-11-01T00:00:00Z |
|  01255999 | 1 - InStorage | 2020-03-01T00:00:00Z | 2019-11-01T00:00:00Z |
|  01255999 | 1 - InStorage | 2020-04-01T00:00:00Z | 2019-11-01T00:00:00Z |
|  01255999 | 1 - InStorage | 2020-05-01T00:00:00Z | 2019-11-01T00:00:00Z |
|  01255999 | 1 - InStorage | 2020-06-01T00:00:00Z | 2019-11-01T00:00:00Z |
|  01255999 | 1 - InStorage | 2020-07-01T00:00:00Z | 2019-11-01T00:00:00Z |
|  01255999 | 1 - InStorage | 2020-08-01T00:00:00Z | 2019-11-01T00:00:00Z |
|  01255999 | 1 - InStorage | 2020-09-01T00:00:00Z | 2019-11-01T00:00:00Z |
|  01255999 | 1 - InStorage | 2020-11-01T00:00:00Z | 2019-11-01T00:00:00Z |
|  01255999 | 1 - InStorage | 2020-12-01T00:00:00Z | 2019-11-01T00:00:00Z |
|  01255999 | 1 - InStorage | 2020-12-15T00:00:00Z | 2019-11-01T00:00:00Z |
|  01255999 | 2 - RentedOut | 2021-01-01T00:00:00Z | 2020-12-15T00:00:00Z |
|  01255999 | 1 - InStorage | 2021-03-01T00:00:00Z | 2021-01-01T00:00:00Z |
|  01255999 | 1 - InStorage | 2021-04-01T00:00:00Z | 2021-01-01T00:00:00Z |
|  01255999 | 2 - RentedOut | 2021-04-02T00:00:00Z | 2021-04-01T00:00:00Z |
|  01255999 | 3 - Service   | 2021-04-05T00:00:00Z | 2021-04-02T00:00:00Z |
|  01255999 | 4 - Repairs   | 2021-04-15T00:00:00Z | 2021-04-05T00:00:00Z |
|  01255999 | 2 - RentedOut | 2021-04-20T00:00:00Z | 2021-04-15T00:00:00Z |
|  01255999 | 5 - Sold      | 2021-05-27T00:00:00Z | 2021-04-20T00:00:00Z |
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it in two steps.

First, use `LAG() OVER ()` to check if a status has changed or not, and record the dates where the status has changed.

Then, use `MAX() OVER ()` to propagate  those dates forwards to fill in the NULLs *(on rows where the status has not changed)*.

```
WITH
  check_for_changes AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    CASE WHEN LAG(machineStatus) OVER (PARTITION BY machineID ORDER BY statusDate) = machineStatus THEN NULL ELSE statusDate END  statusChangeDate
  FROM
    machineStatus
)
SELECT
  *,
  MAX(statusChangeDate) OVER (PARTITION BY machineID ORDER BY statusDate)   AS lastStatusChangeDate
FROM
  check_for_changes
ORDER BY
  statusDate
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/195e8/1

Comment: Thanks Mat. It worked well. I was a bit hesitant to use window functions, since I heard that performance is not so good. Especially, when there are more than one in the same query. What can you say about that statement?

Thank you also for enlightening me about the MAX() OVER. I wasnt aware that this exists.

Comment: Anyone that makes blanket statements like that tend to not know what they're talking about. I'd expect windowed functions to be cheaper that a correlated sub-query. Best advice look at execution plans and use tools such as SQL server profiler to understand expected and actual query cost and performance. And ignore anyone that can't justify sweeping statements with concrete examples.

Comment: Thanks, I also agree that blank statements like that are a bit... BS. Even more, when there is not a clear evidence presented. One last question- if I want to do the opposite of this query and get the date until a given status is valid, it seems that something goes wrong. Can you spot what is the issue? The newStatusStartDate column: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/195e8/3/0

Comment: You should Really ask a new question, not comment on an answer about new requirements.  That said, I think you want this; http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/195e8/6 (If you want to copy values in the other direction, you need to reverse the ORDER BY and use MIN rather than MAX)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to compute a group number and take the last date from the previous group.

```
with g as(
  select machineId, statusDate,  machineStatus, sum(flag) over(partition by machineId order by statusDate) grp
  from (
    select *, case lag(machineStatus, 1, machineStatus) over(partition by machineId order by statusDate) when machineStatus then 0 else 1 end flag
    from #machineStatus) s
) 
select machineId, statusDate, machineStatus
    , (select top(1) g2.statusDate 
       from g g2 
       where g2.machineId = g1.machineId and g2.grp < g1.grp 
       order by g2.statusDate desc) lastChange
from g g1
order by statusDate
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ac795fc53c411ea683ea94c4d259451f)

Comment: The correlated sub-query fetches the wrong date. The op wants the date of the status change, you fetch the last date of the previous status.  Also, the op wants to remove leading nulls, which your answer doesn't do (though fixing the first mistake will inherently fix this too).

Comment: Your query and two possible fixes : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=03b8cc7b32fcf88d3a06044726839351

Comment: This is how  the original OP desired output requiered.  Leaving  it as is because the other solutions return dates the other way.

Comment: This query doesn't generate results matching anything in the Op's edit history.

Answer (score 0):

You use `COALESCE` to get rid of `NULL`

```
SELECT  s.*,
        COALESCE((
            SELECT  MAX(ss.statusDate)
            FROM    #machineStatus ss
            WHERE ss.machineID = s.machineID
                AND ss.machineStatus <> s.machineStatus
                AND ss.statusDate < s.statusDate
        ),
        (
            SELECT  MIN(ss.statusDate)
            FROM    #machineStatus ss
            WHERE ss.machineID = s.machineID
                AND ss.machineStatus = s.machineStatus
                AND ss.statusDate <= s.statusDate
        ))  AS statusChangeDate
FROM    #machineStatus s
ORDER BY s.statusDate;
```

Comment: The second correlated sub-query doesn't need to be correlated on the date. The result is going to be the same for every input date, that's point of the query, it's looking for that machine's first date. It doesn't need to be correlated on the status either. Removing those last two conditions will make that correlated sub-query substantially cheaper by requiring only one evaluation per machine.